# What is this pop-in from the bottom of Chrome for Android?

Tags: chrome-for-android

I'm suffering from a pop-in, coming in from the bottom of the screen, in Chrome for Android.

[image]

It seems to be doing a Google search with whatever text I may have tapped. There's no button to close, and it's much more of a nuisance than a help.

What is it, and how do I turn it off?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**This is Chrome for Android's feature known as Touch to Search.**

The user can tap a word to let Google search quickly without leaving the current page.

From [Google Chrome Help - Search the web on Chrome](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95440?co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid&hl=en),

> #### Search for words
>
> You can find more info about a specific word or phrase on a page with Touch to Search.
>
> **Important**: To use Touch to Search, Google must be [set as your default search engine](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95426?co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid&oco=1).
>
> 1. On your Android device, open the Chrome app.
> 2. Open a page.
> 3. To highlight a word on a page, tap it or touch and hold it.
> 4. To show search results for the highlighted word, tap the panel that opens at the bottom of the page.
>
> **Turn Touch to Search on or off**
>
> 1. On your Android device, open the Chrome app.
> 2. Tap More > Settings > **Google services**.
> 3. Tap **Touch to Search**.
> 4. Turn **Touch to Search** on or off.